# Audio Real Time Monitoring

Tags: sound

I have Intel on board sound. I have been trying to listen on headphones to input sound from microphone, Rakarrack etc.

The sound from the microphone will show as an Input Level in the Sound Settings window but I can't hear it in the headphones. Similarly with Rakarrack, the sound meters show sound produced, but I cannot hear it on the headphones. The Pulse Audio Volume control only shows System sounds for a Playback option, but an ALSA plug in for the browser pops up when I play youtube for example.

Can you help please? I have `qjackctl` installed but can't make any sense out of it because I can't get any sound out.